# Coldfusion - How can I remove a '#' character from a file name

Tags: coldfusion

I'm running into a problem when trying to upload certain files. If a file has a '#' in the name, I get errors when trying to then open the file. Is there a way to strip the '#' character from the filename before uploading it?

I've tried using Replace, but it throws an error when I use '#' in there:

```
<cfset myfile = #Replace('myfile', '#', '', 'all')#>
```

I could use createUUID, but there may be multiple file types, so I don't necessarily know what the file extension will be.

Comment: Show the code used when you tried `replace()`. My guess is that you were not escaping the `#` correctly.

Comment: <cfset myfile = #Replace('myfile', '#', '', 'all')#>

Comment: *"If a file has a '#' in the name, I get errors when trying to then open the file."* what are the errors? that shouldn't be causing errors.. Rather than renaming the files, properly opening them in such a way that doesn't result in errors will likely be the better/easier fix.

Comment: It's a 403 error.  Forbidden.  Access is denied.

Comment: Pound signs have a special meaning in CF. To indicate a literal `#`, you must escape it by using `##`: `Replace(text, "##", "", "all")`. Side note, just saying something "throws an error" does not tell us much. If you are getting an error, please include the *actual error message* [within your question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/26065417/edit).

Comment: Well, I've fixed the file string using Replace.  But how can I strip the '#' character from the actual file before/after it's been uploaded to a directory?

Comment: You can't do it before.  The documentation on cffile probably has hints on how to do it either during the upload or after.  I could look it up, but then again, so could you.

Comment: *what the file extension will be.* Read the docs on [CFFile](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cffile). It returns a structure of details about the file, including extension. Personally I prefer to use my own naming convention for file uploads. Then store it and the "user friendly name" in the database for display purposes.

Answer (score 2):

When you upload the file, use `reReplace()` to remove any non alpha numeric characters in the final name of the file. You might also consider replacing spaces with underscores and/or making the name all lowercase letters.

Comment: An underscore is a non alpha numeric.

Comment: Ok, so replace spaces with underscores, then remove all alpha numeric characters except for underscores. :P